# "Climbing" a binary tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree

Is there some way to climb tree directly to the number without visiting other branches?
For example if I have number 11 I have to visit it going to 2 then to 5 and than to 11 without any kind of search.

```
                                 0
                            /         \
                           /           \
                          /             \
                        1                2
                      /    \           /    \
                     /      \         /      \ 
                    3        4        5       6
                   / \      / \      / \     / \
                  /   \    /   \    /   \   /   \
                 7     8  9    10   11  12  13  14
```

I have killed a lot of time the only thing I got by now is that to get the first route(1 or 2) of number N you have to (n-1)/2 till n is equal to 1 or 2.
Example:
(12 - 1)/2 => (5 - 1)/2 => 2. (7-1)/2=>(3-1)/2 => 1. (11-1)/5=>(2-1)/2 => 1. 
But end then it would be correct to cut the root (0) and treat 2 like a new one:

```
          2
         / \
        /   \
       /     \
     5        6
    / \      / \
   /   \    /   \ 
  11   12  13   14

         to

          0
         / \
        /   \
       /     \
     1        2
    / \      / \
   /   \    /   \ 
  3     4  5     6
```

Solution:

```
int climb(int ID, Tree<int> t)
{

    int time = 0;
    if (tree.exists()) {
        time += t.value();
        tree t1, t2;
        t.branches(t1, t2);
        int branch = ID;
        while (branch > 2) branch = (branch - 1)/2;
        int offset = 1;
        while (offset*2 < ID - 1) offset *= 2;
        if (aux == 1) time += climb(ID - offset2/, a1);
        if (aux == 2) time += climb(ID - offset, a2);
    }
    return time;
}
```

You can access ANY(1, 5, 13, etc) element of full binary tree.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is 'traverse', not 'climb'. Also, recursion is the usual essence of a solution

Comment: Traverse normally search trough all till find and I know how to do this one, but I propose "climbing" that access only those trees that are exactly on the way.

Comment: It depends, is your tree a perfect binary tree (all leaves are at the same depth, and in every parent has two children)? Are the values of nodes like in the example? If the answer to both questions is yes then yes you can do what you want. If no, then no you cannot.

Comment: It is exactly that kind of tree. Among other things the offset for left brunch is two times less then offset of the right one.

Comment: I think I am getting it.
offset = 2^m, so that m is number of line less 2:

Comment: I think I am getting it.

offset = 2^m, so that m is number of line less 2:
m = 1;
while (m*2 < ID) m*2;
so if ID=7..14 m = 4 and for ID = 11..14 m*2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip going through all nodes in between use a hash container (e.g. `std::map` or `std::set`) and hash search. Binary trees are meant to be traversed recursively. Note that `set` is not associative so you'll have to work around it a bit.

If you try too hard to add customized code/member-variables to tree/tree-nodes you might end up with a tree impl that's heavy on memory (answer by David is a very bright example of this).

-- edit --

If your IDs are always a sequence without too many holes (e.g. `0, 1, 2,..., 50` OR `68, 69,...,230,231`) I recommend the plain old array! Let me know if you want to know more.

In general my msg is to pick the right container/structure first, and then only if needed make "minor" modifications to the structure itself.

Comment: I am not sure, I am still a newbie.
I was not very clear I think. 0 1 2...2N-2 are just reference and they are NOT stored inside the tree. It is all about storing less.

Comment: @user1021852 ?? which part are you no sure abt?

Comment: If you know nothing, then start with "hash search" and "tree search". E.g. http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cs113/spring-2000/hash/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree, then you'll understand better what each structure uses internally.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a perfect binary tree (all leaves are at the same depth, and in every parent has two children) and the values of all nodes are like in the example you provided.

In this case, notice the following:

> - A node n has as children the nodes with values 2*n+1, 2*n+2
> - If you want to go to a node with odd value K, then its parent is the node (K-1)/2
> - If you want to visit a node with even value K, its parent is the node (K-2)/2

You repeat the same procedure since you reach node 0 and you have all the nodes you have to visit.

So for your example you want to visit node 11.

```
11 is odd so its parent is (11-1)/2 = 5
5 is odd so its parent is (5-1)/2 = 2
2 is even so its parent is (2-2)/0 = 0

we have reached the root node, so you have to follow the path 0->2->5->11
```

Comment: You assume that keys are always a full sequence. In that case as I suggested a plain old array should be best/fastest.

Comment: I already did this and I use integer division so I do not care if it is odd.
But thx any way.

Comment: @thekashyap Totally agree about the container.

Comment: @user1021852 Odd/even is important if you are going from root down to your child. even -> go right, odd -> go left. So for the sequence 2,5,11 you have to take the right branch, then the left and then the left.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to "climb" to any branch or leaf without accessing  branches that are not in the way(if I am climbing to '4' then I go directly 0 -> 2 -> 4). And only path I missed was offset that will "morph" branch to tree(see question).

I am getting offset like that:

```
int offset = 1;
while (offset*2 < ID - 1) offset *= 2;
```

It works for branch '2' and offset/2 will work for branch '1'.

```
int climb(int ID, Tree<int> t)
{

    int time = 0;
    if (tree.exists()) {
        time += t.value();
        tree t1, t2;
        t.branches(t1, t2);
        int branch = ID;
        while (branch > 2) branch = (branch - 1)/2;
        int offset = 1;
        while (offset*2 < ID - 1) offset *= 2;
        if (aux == 1) time += climb(ID - offset2/, a1);
        if (aux == 2) time += climb(ID - offset, a2);
    }
    return time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way was to make a stack:

```
void solve(int n)
{
  stack<direction> path;
 //Calculate the way 
  while (n > 0)
  {
    if (n & 1) // if n is odd;
      path.push_back(left);
    else
      path.push_back(right);

    n = (n - 1) / 2;
  }

  //Do actual "climbing"

  while (!path.empty())
  {
    if (path.top() == left)
    {
      go left
    }
    else
    {
      go right
    }

    path.pop();
  }
}
```

Thx to Raving_Zealot from linux.org.ru